# Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child() - Receiving data from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a problem with my android app. I'm making a simple learning app for my school project, and i need a string with theory to everysingle topic I would create. To make it I used database from which I'm taking out questions for my tests, and tried to get them with similiar database reference, but with less arguments.

But there is a problem, on QuestionsActivity the "category" variable which is responsible for taking the out specific category name is working fine, but the same scheme on the SetsActivity (where I want to put theory into TextView) returns me "null".

Activity Code:

```
package com.example.klikzdaj;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class SetsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();

    private GridView gridView;

    private TextView tekst;
    private String category;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sets);

        tekst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tekst);
        category = getIntent().getStringExtra("category");

        myRef.child("SETS").child(category).child("theory").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String s = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                tekst.setText(" "+ s);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra("title"));

        gridView = findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(getIntent().getIntExtra("sets",0),getIntent().getStringExtra("title"));
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
        finish();
    }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Database:

```
{
  "Class1" : {
    "category1" : {
      "name" : "adding",
      "sets" : 5,
      },
      "url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/klikzdaj.appspot.com/o/Klasa1%2Fdodawnie.jpg?alt=media&token=b85e0b97-c1cb-401f-9201-b4303efc3313"
    },
    "category2" : {
      "name" : "multiply",
      "sets" : 3,
      "url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/klikzdaj.appspot.com/o/Klasa1%2Fodejmowanie.jpg?alt=media&token=69b992ba-6efb-4da8-94fe-f0f27ff73474"
    },
    "category3" : {
      "name" : "youtube",
      "sets" : 15,
      "url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/klikzdaj.appspot.com/o/Klasa1%2Fdodawnie.jpg?alt=media&token=b85e0b97-c1cb-401f-9201-b4303efc3313"
    }
  },
  "class2" : {
    "category1" : {
      "name" : "divide",
      "sets" : 3,
      "url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/klikzdaj.appspot.com/o/Klasa1%2Fdodawnie.jpg?alt=media&token=b85e0b97-c1cb-401f-9201-b4303efc3313"
    }
  },
  "SETS" : {
    "adding" : {
      "questions" : {
        "wdbjhawb" : {
          "correctANS" : "14",
          "optionA" : "9",
          "optionB" : "14",
          "optionC" : "44",
          "optionD" : "17",
          "question" : "where is 14",
          "setNo" : 1
        }
      }
    },
    "youtube" : {
      "questions" : {
        "adwwad" : {
          "correctANS" : "17",
          "optionA" : "15",
          "optionB" : "10",
          "optionC" : "18",
          "optionD" : "17",
          "question" : "where is 17",
          "setNo" : 1
        },
        "sadafgwaf" : {
          "correctANS" : "1",
          "optionA" : "1",
          "optionB" : "2",
          "optionC" : "3",
          "optionD" : "4",
          "question" : "where is 1",
          "setNo" : 1
        }
      },
      "theory" : {
        "text" : "ijawdoijawiodjaoiwdjiojdaiwdioajwd"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope it's understandable, please help :)

Comment: `getIntent().getStringExtra("category")` is `null`.

Comment: Yes, i know. But what to do, to make it delivering me fields "youtube","adding" etc. i've got the same variable used in QuestionActivity where i'm taking out things from "SETS" -> category -> "questions". Intent is the same and it's working fine.

I just don't get it why on that specific Activity is showing null. What should i do to make it show me the same values like in the other Activity.

Comment: There is a fragment of my "QuestionActivity" with Database Reference. In this case category variable is working fine... 

`category = getIntent().getStringExtra("category");
setNo = getIntent().getIntExtra("setNo",1);

        myRef.child("SETS").child(category).child("questions").orderByChild("setNo").equalTo(setNo).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
   list.add(snapshot.getValue(QuestionModel.class));
}

`

Comment: It is rather the question how you may start that `Intent` ...double-check the `Bundle`. And also, it is generally recommended to check if an `Intent` extras `Bundle` has a key and if the value isn't `null`.